# Can I simplify my phone look-up program?

Tags: java

I needed to make a phone number look-up program with 10 contacts. I feel like I can shorten the program up a bit, it seems very long, but I don't know how. Any suggestion? Do I need all of the Java imports?

```
package phoneLookUp;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;


public class phoneLookUp
{
static HashMap<String,String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

// Method getName() will return the name for given number if it is exist in the contact

public static String getName(String number)
{
Set set = contact.entrySet();
Iterator it = set.iterator();

while(it.hasNext())
{
Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)it.next();

String tNum = (String)me.getValue();

if(tNum.equals(number))
{
return (String)me.getKey();
}

}

//if given number is not found

return "";
}

// Method getNumber() will return the Name of the given phone number if it is exist in the contact


public static String getNumber(String name)
{
Set set = contact.entrySet();
Iterator it = set.iterator();

while(it.hasNext())
{
Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)it.next();

String tName = (String)me.getKey();

if(tName.equals(name))
{
String formattedNumber = outputFormat((String)me.getValue());
return formattedNumber;
}

}

// if name if not found in the contact

return "";
}

// Formatting the given phone number


public static String outputFormat(String phone)
{
String temp = "(";

for(int i = 0; i < phone.length(); i++)
{
if(i < 2)
temp += phone.charAt(i);

else if(i == 2)
temp += phone.charAt(i)+") ";

else if(i < 5)
temp += phone.charAt(i);

else if(i == 5)
temp += phone.charAt(i)+" - ";

else
temp += phone.charAt(i);
}

return temp;

}

public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

// contacts

contact.put("Tom","6037571122");
contact.put("Alice","6037779057");
contact.put("George","6037779103");
contact.put("Ben", "6031234322");
contact.put("Jack","6037764522");
contact.put("Greg","6039985434");
contact.put("Franklin","60344578993");
contact.put("Sam", "6033458765");
contact.put("Mike","6036673322");
contact.put("Alex", "6035561199");




System.out.println("Welcome to the Phone Look up Program ");


char ch = ' ';

do
{
System.out.print("please enter the name or phone number ( no delemeters please) (q to quit) : ");
String input = sc.next();

ch = input.charAt(0);

if(ch == 'q')
break;

// Finding whether given input is Name or Phone Number

if(Character.isDigit(ch))
{
String name = getName(input);

if(!name.equals(""))
System.out.println("Number : "+outputFormat(input)+" belongs to : "+name);

else
System.out.println("There is no listing for : "+outputFormat(input));
}

else
{
String phone = getNumber(input);

if(!phone.equals(""))
System.out.println(input+"'s"+" phone number is : "+phone);

else
System.out.println("There is no listing for : "+input);
}


}while(true);

}

}
```

This is my output:

> Welcome to the Phone Look up Program
>   please enter the name or phone number ( no delemeters please) (q to quit) : Alice
>   Alice's phone number is : (603) 777 - 9057
>   please enter the name or phone number ( no delemeters please) (q to quit) : Tom
>   Tom's phone number is : (603) 757 - 1122
>   please enter the name or phone number ( no delemeters please) (q to quit) : Sally
>   There is no listing for : Sally
>   please enter the name or phone number ( no delemeters please) (q to quit) : q

Comment: quick question: Are you using an IDE? Eclipse **and** Netbeans both mark unused imports as Warnings (which is what they are at compile time).

Comment: I'm using eclipse and their are no errors. Its just that I didn't know if there was another way to make this program without using so many imports

Comment: Why do you use a parameterized map but raw `Set`s and `Iterator`s?

Comment: You should format your program using proper indentation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes , you don't need to iterate through the map to know if it contains a certain value or not, you can just call `get`

```
 String contact = contacts.get(name);
 if(contact == null){
  // no such value
 }
```

You might have notice that I called it `contacts` instead of `contact`, because a map is a collection that holds things and things are plural.
**Note:** If you need to iterate over a map, don't use iterator, use `enhanced-for` instead.

```
for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry: map.entrySet()){

}
```

any language you use, you have to follow its naming conventions. Use Pascal casing for classes in Java

```
    class PhoneLookUp
```

and not

```
    class phoneLookUp
```

Use StringBuilder instead of String when you need to append frequently. Every time you do `+=` on a `String`, it creates a new String because strings are immutable in Java, consider using `StringBuilder` instead.

```
  public static String outputFormat(String phone)
  {
  StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder("(");

   for(int i = 0; i < phone.length(); i++)
   {
   if(i < 2){
     temp.append(phone.charAt(i));
   }
   else if(i == 2){
    temp.append(phone.charAt(i)+") ");
   }
   .....
  return temp.toString();

  }
```

Comment: So how would my code change? What do I delete/add?

Comment: @user57030 you replace your iterations by calling get

Answer (score 3):

#### Making it shorter

It would be better to create two maps:

1. One to map names to numbers (like the current `contact` map)
2. One to map numbers to names

Also add a `registerEntry(name, number)` function to register entries in both maps at the same time.

Then the implementation can be simpler, like this:

```
private static Map<String, String> namesToNumbers = new HashMap<String, String>();
private static Map<String, String> numbersToNames = new HashMap<String, String>();

private static void registerEntry(String name, String number) {
    namesToNumbers.put(name, number);
    numbersToNames.put(number, name);
}

static {
    registerEntry("Tom", "6037571122");
    registerEntry("Alice", "6037779057");
    registerEntry("George", "6037779103");
    registerEntry("Ben", "6031234322");
    registerEntry("Jack", "6037764522");
    registerEntry("Greg", "6039985434");
    registerEntry("Franklin", "60344578993");
    registerEntry("Sam", "6033458765");
    registerEntry("Mike", "6036673322");
    registerEntry("Alex", "6035561199");
}

public static String getName(String number) {
    String name = numbersToNames.get(number);
    return name == null ? "" : name;
}

public static String getNumber(String name) {
    String number = namesToNumbers.get(name);
    return number == null ? "" : outputFormat(number);
}
```

#### Code review

There are many other problems with this program:

- Use `CamelCase` for class names. Instead of `phoneLookUp`, `PhoneLookUp`
- Declare variables using interface types instead of implementation. Instead of `HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>()`, use `Map<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>()`
- Don't use raw types like `Set`. Use types with their correct template parameter, for example `Set<String>`

Comment: Small addition to the point you made about naming: package names, by convention, should be all lowercase.

Comment: this code gave me a lot of errors

Comment: @user57030 If you mention the errors you have with this code, the easier it will be to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, it's `delimiter`, not `delemeter`.

Second, here's one suggestion for `outputFormat`. Assuming if you are strictly dealing with only 10-digit `String`s, you can also consider using regular expressions to run pattern matching on the input:

```
private static final String outputFormat(final String input) {
    if (input == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(new NullPointerException());
    }
    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})").matcher(input);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong number.");
    }
    return String.format("(%s) %s-%s", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3));
}
```

The regular expression `(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})` will break down a 10-digit `String` `input` into three groups of numbers, the first two with three digits each and finally a four-digit number. These go into `matcher.group(1)...matcher.group(3)` if `input` is successfully matched against the regular expression.

The three matched output `String`s are 'placed' into the format indicated by `String.format()`, where `"%s"` represents a `String` value. This gives us the desired output.

For completeness, we should validate against `input` as well, a basic check for `null` and then for the outcome of the pattern matching.